# How to share geolocation from mobile device to web-app

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mobile, web-applications, geolocation

I created a mobile web-app to rate places (such as restaurant, coffee etc) in my city.

So far I use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` of the geolocation API to get the place's coordinates in the form when users create the "place's post". I try to avoid a maximum in the process to force the user to write an address they most of time don't know by heart..

```
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showError(error) {
  switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
      break;
  }
}
```

At that point my main issue is a lot of user have disabled the navigator's location and it's too complicated for them to go back to the settings to do the changes. **In the same time they report me that if they would be invited to share a one-time location, they would accept it.**

As far as I know it's impossible to do so because the navigator's settings take the lead on all web interactions. So once it's disabled, no turning back.

I was wondering what was the most seamless way for the user to share coordinates without touching to its navigator's settings?